# Why struct alignment different in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, struct

I have set the struct alignment in Xcode to 8-byte packing.
For example :

```
struct Info
{
    unsigned short  kindID;
    char            kindName[32];
    int64_t         gameMonery;
}__attribute__ ((aligned(8)));
```

This struct size is 48 byte, both in iPhone5 and iPhone 5S, the `kindName` address offset is 2 byte, but in iPhone5 the `gameMoney` offset is 36 byte, in iPhone 5S the `gameMoney` offset is 40 byte.

Why have this different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment of 64 bit types (`int64_t`) is 4 on 32 bit platforms and 8 on 64 bit platforms.

You can make the compiler suppress alignment of individual elements by adding `__attribute__((packed))` to the declaration. Access of unaligned members is somewhat slower.

The reason why the size of the struct does not differ on both platforms is that the size is subject to the struct's alignment (as specified to 8):

Example:

```
struct { char i; } __attribute__((aligned(8))) foo;
sizeof(foo) == 8;
```

Comment: In 32 bit platforms, the alignment of `int64_t` is 4, then `struct Info` size should be 44(4+32+8).