# My C program prints two different things when it shouldn't

Tags: c, string, pointers, io, binary

It prints one thing if its run on my computer, and a second thing if its ran on any other computer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct hw5_struct {
    char f_name[12];
    char l_name[12];
    int age;
    float height;
}HW5_struct;

typedef struct hw5_struct_updated {
    char *f_name;
    char *l_name;
    char *address;
    int age;
    int birthday;
    float height;
}HW5_struct_updated;

void printThisFile( FILE *file, int fileSize );
void putNewStructuresInFile( FILE *newFile, int matchingFileSize );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    printf("\n");

    const char *fileLocation = argv[1];

    FILE *originalData = fopen( fileLocation, "rb" );

    fseek( originalData, 0L, SEEK_END );
    int originalDataFileSize = ftell( originalData );
    rewind( originalData );
    printf( "The size of the original file is: %d\n", originalDataFileSize );

    HW5_struct_updated *structArray;

    printf("test\n");

    int i = 0;
    HW5_struct tempHW5struct;

    for( i = 0 ; i < originalDataFileSize ; i += sizeof( HW5_struct ) ) { 
        fseek( originalData, i, SEEK_SET );
        fread( &tempHW5struct, sizeof( HW5_struct ), 1, originalData);
        printf( "f_name: %s\nl_name: %s\nage: %d\nheight: %f\n\n", tempHW5struct.f_name, tempHW5struct.l_name, tempHW5struct.age, tempHW5struct.height );
        printf("test\n");
        structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].f_name = tempHW5struct.f_name;

        //strcpy( structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].f_name, tempHW5struct.f_name );

        printf("%s\n", structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].f_name);
        //structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].l_name = tempHW5struct.l_name;
        structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].age = tempHW5struct.age;
        structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].height = tempHW5struct.height;
        structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].birthday = 1;
        //structArray[ i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ].address = "8008 Mulberry Ln";
        printf("structure #%d\n was read", ( i / sizeof( HW5_struct ) ) );
    }   

    FILE *newData = fopen( "my_temp.tmp", "wb");

    for( i = 0 ; i < originalDataFileSize ; i += sizeof( HW5_struct ) ) { 
        fseek( originalData, i, SEEK_SET );
        fread( &tempHW5struct, sizeof( HW5_struct ), 1, originalData );
        printf( "f_name: %s\nl_name: %s\nage: %d\nheight: %f\n\n", tempHW5struct.f_name, tempHW5struct.l_name, tempHW5struct.age, tempHW5struct.height );
    }

    HW5_struct_updated tempHW5structUpdated;

    for( i = 0; i < originalDataFileSize ; i += sizeof( HW5_struct ) ) {
        fseek(newData, i * sizeof( HW5_struct_updated ), SEEK_SET);
        fwrite( &tempHW5structUpdated, sizeof( HW5_struct_updated ), 1, newData);
    }

    return 0;
}

void printThisFile( FILE *file, int fileSize) {
    int i = 0;
    HW5_struct tempStruct;

    for( i = 0 ; i < fileSize ; i += sizeof( HW5_struct ) ) {
        fseek( file, i, SEEK_SET );
        fread( &tempStruct, sizeof( HW5_struct ), 1, file);
        printf( "f_name: %s\nl_name: %s\nage: %d\nheight: %f\n\n", tempStruct.f_name, tempStruct.l_name, tempStruct.age, tempStruct.height );
    }
}
```

this is on a server so each person connects to the server, has the same .c file, compiles and runs it.

when I run it I get

```
The size of the original file is: 320
test
f_name: Fred
l_name: Hutcheson
age: 32
height: 6.000000

test
Segmentation fault
```

when I run it on my phone or when my friend runs it we get:

```
The size of the original file is: 320
test
f_name: Fred
l_name: cheson
age: 1920098636
height: 0.000000

test
Segmentation fault
```

It is like this with other programs that do simpler things as well, like a program that just `prints("Hello World\n")` will literally do nothing when I run it and will print normally on every other computer, no idea what's going on.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: Did you notice you never used `printThisFile()`?

Comment: Where's your error checking? What if not enough arguments are passed to the program? What if the program fails to open the file? What if you fail to read?

Comment: What are the differences between the two systems? What is your input?

Comment: I have been using c for a solid 3 days, I have no idea what i'm doing

Comment: And if it also happens with simpler programs, why not post those?

Comment: Furthermore `structArray[...].f_name = tempHW5struct.f_name` is wrong. It will make *all* `f_name` pointer point to the very same `tempHW5struct.f_name`.

Comment: "I have been using c for a solid 3 days, I have no idea what i'm doing", then please stop asking complex questions here and learn C first. There are many online and offline resources for that.

Comment: If you're that new you're way in over your head I'd say! Take a few steps back, [get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and *start over*.

Comment: Have a look at the following: [Why struct alignment different in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715726/why-struct-alignment-different-in-ios)

Comment: this is my programming homework  guys, like, i'm a couple days into a class that is supposed to teach me c and this is the homework, my teacher hasn't gone over any of this and i'm just desperately trying to understand.

Comment: Basically, as far as the homework is concerned, **do not read a binary file cross-platform**, instead connect to the official server for all your development activities. Cross-platform differences are nothing to be approached on the first homework

Comment: Alright I will keep that in mind, thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need any of those `fseek` calls - the position within the file gets updated when you read/write from/to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You never allocate memory for `structArray`, or make it point anywhere valid. It is *uninitialized* and will point to an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) location.

Then when you dereference it to write to some seemingly random location you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Since you program in C you could use [*variable-length arrays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) like

```
HW5_struct_updated structArray[originalDataFileSize  / sizeof(HW5_struct)];
```

Comment: So first off thank you, It prints the file correctly now, it assigns the variables into the array correctly, you fixed it! I am very new so i really just don't understand pointers/arrays well enough.